# Regex conditional statement

Tags: regex

so I have been tring to figure out the if function in regex but, can get in the hang of it.

These are the two scenarios that can happen:

- - [MyTag] Random text that can have 0-9 with special case.
- - Random text that can have 0-9 with special case.

what my pattern should do:

IF (text contains "]") 
THEN start from "] "
ELSE start from " - "

I have attempted to reach that with this:
(?(\] )(\].*$)|(\-.*$))

and of course failed. We got the
(\].*$) which collets the part from "] " until END OF LINE has been reached
(\-.*$) collects from "- " until END OF LINE
?(\] ) Which should act as the IF statement

so can someone explain to me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: If you mean to match the rest of line from a hyphen or a `]`, use `[-\]].*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to match any line substring starting with a `-` that has no non-adjacent `]` after it on the same line up to its end, or after a `]`.

Since `]` has priority, it should be the first alternative in the group:

```
(?:\]|-(?!.*]))(.*)
```

See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM9lU5/1), Group 1 will hold the part of line that has no `-` or `]`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the `[MyTag]` bit to be optional, and the remainder of the pattern is the same.

Therefore you could try a pattern that does this:

```
\s*\-\s+(\[\w+\])?(\s.+)$
```

Where the:

- `\s*\-\s+` is the hyphen surrounded by whitespace
- `(\[\w+\])?` is optionally the tag in braces
- `(\s.+)$` is the rest up to the end of the string including the leading single whitespace